# Error while updating the Constraints(X,Y,W,H) based on Rotation?

Tags: ios, autolayout, visual-format-language

Here I used Visual Format Language to handle the AutoLayouts. **If I revert back the Orientation from Landscape to Portrait - Views are not showing correctly.(image(shrink) & 2nd label (Yposition))**. Even in Portrait mode i did not get any Constraints Error messages on **Debugger window**. but if i switch to landscape mode - its printing "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
"

The following code i used:

```
-  (void)addConstraints {

[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_contactImageProperty,_peopleAllowLabelProperty,_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty,_continueBtnProperty);
_contactImageProperty.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_peopleAllowLabelProperty.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_continueBtnProperty.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// contactImageProperty
NSArray *constraints = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contactImageProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0f]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contactImageProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:200]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-30-[_contactImageProperty]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


// peopleAllowLabelProperty
constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_peopleAllowLabelProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_peopleAllowLabelProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:50]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_contactImageProperty]-10-[_peopleAllowLabelProperty]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


// shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:100]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_peopleAllowLabelProperty]-100-[_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


// continueBtnProperty

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_continueBtnProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_continueBtnProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:50]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_continueBtnProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:300]];

constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_continueBtnProperty]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

}

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_peopleAllowLabelProperty,_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty,_continueBtnProperty);
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contactImageProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:200.0f]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_peopleAllowLabelProperty]-200-[_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}
else {
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contactImageProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:100.0f]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:50]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_peopleAllowLabelProperty]-20-[_shareCodesDefaultMessageLabelProperty]-[_continueBtnProperty]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

}

[image: Portrait Orientation]

[image: Landscape Orientation]

[image: Issue Screen]

Answer (score 1):

for the image shrinking, you should force the aspect ratio of the image by adding a constraints to the width of the image depending on the height value.

for the y position, you should add 3 more hidden views that have a same height constraints and the same trailing and heading space to the image, first label, second label and button. Something like that:

```
Image
|
hidden view
|
label 1
|
hidden view
|
label 2
|
hidden view
|
button
```

Equal height for hidden view : something like [hiddenView1(==hiddenView2)]

Equal space between hidden views and elemets : something lile V:[topView]-5-[hiddenView]-5-[bottomView]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Actually i want to revert back the position(Label2) and size (ImageView). So i want to reduce the Height of UIImageView in Landscape mode. while turn into Portrait the height will be a olderValue. And 2nd Label will be the Y position in Landscape is different because the UIScreeen Height!=Portrait Mode.height. So, here we have to change Y value and when turn into Portrait.? Note: i don't want to loose any elements

Comment: For the imageView, what you do is good but as you only change the height the width is kept as it is and the image is shrink. So juste add a constraint to the width like ratio*height. This should make it. Try to avoid thinking with static value, try to work with proportion. if you use what I explained in my answer you should have a fairly good distribution of you views in both portrait and landscape without having to keep value for each size of screen of orientation. If that is not what you expect maybe we need more detail on what you want.

Comment: Simply am asking. In Visual Format language is it possible to update the constraints while doing orientation? if it can you tell me how? Because if concentrate landscape, the portrait mode constraint will not apply. i don't know. So here am creating two different constraints for landscape and portrait. but i want to update the value from existing constraint.? Please look at this example: here you can see what am trying to achieve. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15307735/TypingTextShowUsingAutolayout.zip

Comment: I would prefere using Storyboard for this. Just did some changes on your storyboard, which you could find here http://we.tl/6jrO1BgXTU look at the preview in interface builder (open the assistant editor next to the storyboard > choose Preview) and click on the add button at the bottom to add other screens and orientations. tell me if it this what you expect, or something close to it. we could then fine tune it. let me know

Comment: You just added three hidden views. have you noticed in the **Debugger** window. So many issues about unsatisfied constraints and so. Even if you simply turn into Landscape mode. i need to See all the Elements in Landscape mode. how it was visible in Portrait. If you see my project, there i did without adding hidden views also i achieved rite. but if you add more views we can't view all the elements rite. i mean. if you use ScrollView you can. but i don't want to go with ScrollView. i just want to update the Position and Height of UImageView and Label Constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But still i am finding some solution for this.